# Lower bounds for norms of commutators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

For various reasons I became interested in bounds on the norm of commutators of operators. For instance, if $B(H)$ is the algebra of bounded operators on a Hilbert space, one may ask for a lower bound on $||[A,B]||$ in terms of properties of $A$ and $B$. (It is clear that one can not have simple norm estimates since for $A=1$ one has $[A,B]=0$.) One may consider questions like: Is there a subspace $\Omega$ of $B(H)$ such that $||[A,B]||\geq ||A||$ for all $A\in\Omega$ (keeping $B\in B(H)$ fixed)? More generally, I'm also interested in similar questions for the $L^p$-norm $||A||_p=(\operatorname{tr}|A|^p)^{1/p}$. In the literature, one finds a flora of results concerning upper bounds on norms of commutators (however, for the $L^p$-norm, results are sparse). Is anyone familiar with these types of questions, concerning lower bounds? Can someone point out relevant sources?

Comment: Did you check out: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27345/norms-of-commutators

Comment: Yes, but I didn't say much about lower bounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't address the full generality of your question but it might at least suggest places to hunt in the literature.

Thinking of $B$ as fixed, you're asking for a lower bound on the norm of $\operatorname{ad}_B(A)$ as $A$ varies in some subspace. If we take $A$ to range over all of $B(H)$ then MathSciNet directs me to

> J. G. Stampfli. *The norm of a derivation.*
>   [Pacific J. Math. Volume 33, Number 3 (1970), 737–747](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102976839)

in which it's proved that $\Vert \operatorname{ad}_B \Vert$ is **equal to** twice the distance of $B$ from the subspace ${\mathbb C} I$.

One can consider similar problems for norms of inner derivations on other C*-algebras (the von Neumann case seems apparently behaves just like $B(H)$, see L. Zsido, *The norm of a derivation in a $W^\ast$-algebra*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 38 (1973), 147–150). In the unital case, it seems like a good place to find out what's known is

> [MR2274022 (2008f:46071)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2274022)
>   R. J. Archbold, D. W. B. Somerset. *Measuring noncommutativity in $C^\ast$-algebras.* J. Funct. Anal. 242 (2007), no. 1, 247–271.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into these papers and their references. Looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

The following result is classical: let $\mathbb H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $A,B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb H)$, then
$
[A,B]\not=I.
$
In finite dimension, just take the trace, and if the dimension is infinite, compute $[A,B^N]$.

This indicates that the most interesting questions about commutators are dealing with unbounded operators. The paradigmatic examples are the creation ($A_+$) and annihilation operators
$(A_-)$
$$
A_\pm=D_t\pm i\frac t2,\quad D_t=-i\partial_t.
$$
We have 
$
[A_-,A_+]=I,
$
which is a way to express the uncertainty principle.
$A_+$ is injective with an image of codimension 1 (Fredholm index $-1$) whereas 
$A_-$ is surjective with a kernel of dimension 1 (Fredholm index $1$). In the Hermite basis,
$A_+$ is a forward weighted shift, $A_-$ its adjoint, a backward weighted shift.

An interesting category of unbounded operators is given by pseudodifferential operators: taking $A=a(x,D)$ with order $m_1$, $B=b(x,D)$ with order $m_2$, the principal symbol of the commutator $[A,B]$ is $\frac 1i\{a,b\} $ where $\{a,b\}=\partial_\xi a\cdot \partial_x b-
\partial_x a\cdot \partial_\xi b
$ is the Poisson bracket:
$$
\underbrace{[a(x,D), b(x,D)]}_{\text{order $m_1+m_2-1$}}\equiv\frac 1i\{a,b\}(x,D)  \mod{\text{operators of order $m_1+m_2-2$.}}
$$